# Selenium- How to handle cursor jumping problem

Tags: selenium

I have an application which has a textbox but there is an issue in that textbox that if we type in the textbox the cursor jumps back.
 Below is the demo jsFiddle link-

https://jsfiddle.net/zdennis/xpvt214o/178966

The selenium code I am using to type in the textbox:

```
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("keysToSend");
```

So the original typed text becomes distorted.
In Selenium, How can I handle this situation to make my tests pass?

Comment: Tell your devs to fix it... but I'm assuming you are entering data on some third party site in order to scrape data from it. I'm only seeing the jumping in the Content-editable field on the demo page... which element are you referring to?

Comment: As a last resort, you could us JS to insert the text into the field. For the Content-editable field, you can get the element and set it's `.textContent` to "keysToSend" directly. This is not a user scenario but given how badly this acts, it may be your only option.

Comment: you could override their javascript functions, but why?.  Why would you want this to pass?